# socket.io - I can't use socket.emit() in a socket.on()

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am learning to use node.js and socket.io with react.js. I am having an issue with my sockets. I am currently working on a rock-paper-scissors game to practice, and I have two listeners for my sockets: createRoom and joinRoom. In my joinRoom listener, I would like to send a socket to both members of the room. However, when I am in my socket.on('joinRoom'), I cannot send a socket. Here is some code that might help you better understand my problem:

```
// server-side
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('startGame'); // Works
  socket.on('joinRoom', (data) => {
    socket.emit('startGame'); // Does not work
    socket.to(data.room).emit('startGame'); // Does not work
    io.to(data.room).emit('startGame'); // Does not work
    io.emit('startGame'); // Works but it sends the socket to all clients and that's not what I want
  });
});
```

```
  // client-side
  useEffect(() => {    
    socket.on('startGame', (data) => {
      alert(socket.id);
    });
    
    return () => {
      socket.off('startGame');
    };
  }, [socket]);
```

```
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
const gameController = require('./controller/gameController');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => gameController.socketHandler(io, socket));

server.listen(3001);
module.exports = io;
```

I have already tried changing my code by looking at other examples. I followed the socket.io documentation to the letter, and I even changed the version of socket.io, but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's sorted out, since I'm starting with Node.js, I didn't know, but I had used my useEffect to handle my socket on the client side outside of the component where the emit was located (I don't know if I'm clear).